# Using Include Files with PHP Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, associative

I have an event listing page in a wordpress plugin I mage that is showing a date with times for that date.It shows 14 days worth.

I’ve used an associated array to grab the server date and strip it down to a number. Each day has an include file associated with it.

I’m trying to get it to sort those dates and then include that file so it will show.

When use the following code, it works fine. Shows the key, date, value and name of the include for all the 14 days.

```
$compare = array($getshow1=>("day1.php"),$getshow2=>("day2.php"),$getshow3=> ("day3.php"),$getshow4=>("day4.php"),$getshow5=>("day5.php"),$getshow6=>("day6.php"),$getshow7=>("day7.php"),$getshow8=>("day8.php"),$getshow9=>("day9.php"),$getshow10=>("day10.php"),$getshow11=>("day11.php"),$getshow12=>("day12.php"),$getshow13=>("day13.php"),$getshow14=>("day14.php")); 

ksort($compare);

foreach($compare as $x => $x_value) {
echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
echo "<br>";
}
```

However when change it to the following sorth to try and use the includes, it works but for some reason only shows on about half of the 14.

```
ksort($compare);

foreach($compare as $x => $x_value) {
include $x_value;

}
```

I’m thinking there is some function I need to use but I’ve working on this a while now and think I have code block.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please post your error, code looks ok, you need to print `$compare` how many index it have. Is there any reason to using `ksort()`?

Comment: I was using ksort because it seemed to be the only one sorting from low to high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the sorting would not work if any of the fields were empty. So, I created a null value for each field and had it auto add that value if the user didn't enter a value when filling out the data.

Using the getshow or $getshow in between '' did not work as it just sorted on that an not the actual variable that needs to be pulled in to each one of the 14. I dropped the '' and now with the no blanks everything is working as I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

use associative array key as string it will work fine :)
Make sure that your php file should be in same directory if it is in different directory than define its proper path in array value.

your array should look like this

```
  $compare = array(
    'getshow1'=> "day1.php",
    'getshow2'=> "day2.php",
    'getshow3'=> "day3.php",
    'getshow4'=> "day4.php",
    'getshow5'=> "day5.php",
    'getshow6'=> "day6.php",
    'getshow7'=> "day7.php"
    );
```

and try again

```
ksort($compare);

foreach($compare as $x => $x_value){
   include $x_value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I would of never thought of doing the array like that. It's working perfect now!!!

Comment: Well, I spoke a little to soon. While it now does show all the listings, I can't get it to sort from lowest to high value of the strings. I've tried the various sort types and nothing seems to sort them by the values in the getshow strings.